# How to open advanced tab of Advanced User Accounts using command line?

Tags: windows, user-accounts

Is there a specific run command to directly open the advanced (second) tab of Advanced User Accounts, netplwiz or control userpasswords2?

Netplwiz and userpasswords 2 opens the 1st tab, but I want to directly open the 2nd (advanced tab) from the run box or command prompt.

I have tried variants as well as exhaustive internet searches, nothing which helped. The syntax should resemble something like below...but none work. Can anyone help please? Thanks!

```
explorer {98641F47-8C25-4936-BEE4-C2CE1298969D} -page\advanced
Rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Rundll_netplwiz
control userpasswords2 (parameter?)
control /name netplwiz (parameter?)
control /name userpasswords2
```

Comment: I dont think they have any parameters available, not that I can find.

Comment: It looks like netplwiz, because it is an exe file, doesn't respond to the same parameter lines cpl files do. Do you know how to find out what parameters an exe file has? I also tried using Process Explorer to find the command line path and it just pointed to netplwiz.exe, with no other arguments.

Comment: I don't think there are any, I have scoured the internet, nothing.